# Nginx TTL SecurLink Not Working

Tags: php, nginx, ttl

I am trying to create Time Limited links on Nginx...

I have a PHP script that adds a md5hash of time and secretcode to the URL and then nginx is supposed to read and compare the time to see if the link should be alive or not...  As it is, its not working...  It returns 403 for everything that has the $st and $arg_e

I have a server guy, so the nginx stuff is not mine (he put it) and im not the best with it....  SO i need ur help if you can...

Here is the PHP script that i run all the traffic through to append the secretcode and the timeout argument...  This is basically just a script to add the tokens "&st=" and "&e=" to the URL

```
<?php

$params = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];


define(URL_TIMEOUT, 120); # 2min timeout
$secret = "xxxmysecretxxx";
$time = pack('N', time() + URL_TIMEOUT);
$timeout = bin2hex($time);

$hashmac = md5($secret.$time);

$url = "http://mytracker.net"."/".$params."&st=".$hashmac."&e=".$timeout;

header('location: '.$url);
//echo $url;
?>
```

Here is the Nginx config with specification to the /protected folder

```
location /protected {
    secure_link_md5 xxxmysecretxxx$arg_e;
    secure_link $arg_st,$arg_e;

    if ($secure_link = "") {
        return 403;
    }

    if ($secure_link = "0") {
        return 403;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        secure_link_md5 xxxmysecretxxx$arg_e;
        secure_link $arg_st,$arg_e;

        if ($secure_link = "") {
            return 403;
        }

        if ($secure_link = "0") {
            return 403;
        }
        #try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Would love some help as to what im doing wrong?

The expectation is that server would check the time stamp against the current time and if its past 2min from the time the hash was created then show a 403, if not show the page...

Please chime in...

Answer (score 1):

Nginx uses a "special" md5 checksum. "*Special*" like "*binary, base64encoded and with some characters replaced*".

You can see that at the command line example in the [nginx manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html#secure_link_md5):

```
echo -n '2147483647/s/link127.0.0.1 secret' | \
    openssl md5 -binary | openssl base64 | tr +/ -_ | tr -d =
```

You can achieve something similar with php like:

```
$md5 = md5($your_secure_parameters);
$nginx_md5 = base64_encode(hex2bin($md5));
$nginx_md5 = str_replace(array('+', '/', '='), array('-', '_', ''), $nginx_md5);
```

Further I think the `bin2hex` and `pack` calls on the timestamp are too much.

Comment: Sweet, i think that worked!  I now see the page and it seems the link is alive for 2min...    You wouldnt happen to know the extra time this would add to a redirect would you?  Also, anything you would change about the nginx config?  Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the first question. The nginx configuration contains the same part twice. Also one should use `$secure_link_expires` inside `secure_link_md5` for the timestamp, not the variable which one specified in `secure_link`. Maybe you should also put `$uri` into the checksum, to harden the security.

Comment: What i mean by the first question is; how much overhead time do you think is incorporated into the md5hash?   Ie. how many milliseconds do you think this procedure adds into getting to the page?

Comment: One cannot tell that in any time unit. Try it out (on the hardware you want to use!), if you are interested in your case. In general I think this overhead is negligible.